# mysql: mysterious sideways single quote and IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries I can run and will get 2 totally different results, solely because I use a "sideways single quote" versus a single quote. See below:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE 'natural' IS NOT NULL
```

Will return every record regardless if the "natural" column is set to NULL

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE `natural` IS NOT NULL
```

Will **correctly** only return records where there are values set for the column "natural"

That ain't right.

Comment: The `sideways single quote` is usually called a `backtick`. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first example `'natural' IS NOT NULL` tests to see if the string literal `'natural'` is not null. Since string literals are always not null, this condition will always be true.

The second example tests the value of the column with the name `natural`. This is what you want.

**Related**

[String literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html)

> A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (`'`) or double quote (`"`) characters.

[Schema object names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html)

> The identifier quote character is the backtick ( ` )

Comment: Thanks. I was (figuratively) tearing my hair out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is behaving correctly.  `'natural'` is a string value so `'natural' IS NOT NULL` will always evaluate to true.